# Ajax confirmation is asking only for one data

Tags: php, ajax

I have implemented an ajax beforeSend function where there is a confirm(), the problem is that in the code if I want to delete the first value in while it asks for confirm but if I click the second or third or fourth, it just goes to the URL in the method and executes the command

this is the the page

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Button</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people");
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<form method="post" id="del" action="delete.php">
<input type='hidden' id='pid' name='pid' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
<button id="send" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
} 
?>
```

this is the ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#del").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          url: "delete.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
          cache: false,
      processData:false,
      beforeSend:function(){
         return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
      },
      success: function(data)
        {

         alert("Delete Successful");
    window.location.reload(); 

        },
        error: function(e) 
        {

        }           
     });
  }));
});
```

whereas it should ask no matter which record I want to delete, it should ask for confirmation.

Comment: Your while loop produces multiple forms with with the same id hence u are getting the problem. ID must be unique

Comment: Form, button and hidden elements ids are getting repeated. Those all should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `classname` `class="del"` instead of `id` `id="del"`.Each time submit its only execute first form

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Button</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people");
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<form method="post" class="del" action="delete.php">
<input type='hidden' class='pid' name='pid' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
<button id="send" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you create invalid HTML:

while(...)
   {
     ...
     
     '>
     Delete
   ...
   }

In every loop-run you create 3 objects with identical id in each run. An ID must not defined multiple times.

Solutions:

- Don't use `id=`and use optional `class=`.
- Append an unique number to id, e.g. `id="del-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`